# AngularJS: Two-way Data binding using mySQL database

Tags: mysql, angularjs, cherrypy

I'm currently working on something to teach myself AngularJS, and I'm running issue with two-way data binding. I have now set it up to obtain the information from the database.

When I call the link, I receive the information from the database. I first search for the user. In this case, I searched for Juana Castillo.

```
localhost:8080/api/person?name=Juana+Castillo
```

The information that returned after "searching" for Juana Castillo is the following:

```
{
    "count": "1", 
    "input": null, 
    "results": {
        "DateOfBirth": "12/24/1999", 
        "secPosition": "Goalkeeper", 
        "ACT": "20", 
        "Email": "jcastillo@fake.com", 
        "ParentApproval": 0, 
        "Views": "/trunk/files/f00000.txt", 
        "EmailConfidential": 1, 
        "Address": "2 Av. Pres. Castelo Branco, Rio de Janeiro, Brazil", 
        "SAT": "900", 
        "Name": "Juana Castillo", 
        "Level": "Amateur", 
        "CountryPlayingIn": "Brazil", 
        "GPA": 3.5, 
        "Graduation": "May 2016", 
        "priPosition": "Goalkeeper", 
        "Gender": "F", 
        "PhoneNumber": "55 800 062 7222", 
        "Citizenship": "Brazilian", 
        "Links": "/trunk/files/f00000.txt", 
        "Videos": "/trunk/files/f00000.txt", 
        "FieldOfStudy": "/trunk/files/f00003.txt", 
        "Committed": "/trunk/files/f00000.txt", 
        "Sport": "Soccer", 
        "TOEFL": "28"
    }, 
    "method": "GET", 
    "kwargs": {
        "name": "Juana Castillo"
    }
}
```

My question is, after getting this information, what is usually the way people do two-way data binding to show this information to the front end?

I've built my webpage using the following:

1. AngularJS
2. CherryPy Server
3. MySQL database

Things I'm ***not*** using are:

1. PHP

Currently, my first time working with anything that has to do with obtaining information from the database, and I'm presently unsure on how to show this information on the front end.

Here's my attempt:

```
app.controller('PlayerCtrl', ['$scope',
                       '$location',
                       '$log',
                       '$window',
                       '$rootScope',
                       'Person',
                       function ($scope,
    $location,
    $log,
    $window,
    $rootScope,
    Person) {

    $scope.options;
    $scope.Name;
    $scope.Email;
    $scope.Summary;
    $scope.Position;
    $scope.Gpa;
    $scope.Gender;
    $scope.priPosition;
    $scope.secPosition;
    $scope.ACT;
    $scope.SAT;
    $scope.TOEFL;
    $scope.Citizenship;
    $scope.FieldOfStudy;
    $scope.Sport;
    $scope.Country;
    $scope.Address;
    $scope.DateOfBirth;
    $scope.Level;

    // function for snagging specific DB entries
    $scope.getPage = function (searchOption) {
        Person.get(searchOption).$promise.then(function (data) {
            var pulledData = [];
            pulledData = data.results;
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.Email = pulledData["Email"];
                $scope.Name = pulledData["Name"];
                $scope.Summary = pulledData["Summary"];
                $scope.Position = pulledData["Position"];
                $scope.Gpa = pulledData["GPA"];
                $scope.Gender = pulledData["Gender"];
                $scope.priPosition = pulledData["priPosition"];
                $scope.secPosition = pulledData["secPosition"];
                $scope.ACT = pulledData["ACT"];
                $scope.SAT = pulledData["SAT"];
                $scope.TOEFL = pulledData["TOEFL"];
                $scope.Citizenship = pulledData["Citizenship"];
                $scope.FieldOfStudy = pulledData["FieldOfStudy"];
                $scope.Sport = pulledData["Sport"];
                $scope.Country = pulledData["CountryPlayingIn"];
                $scope.Address = pulledData["Address"];
                $scope.DateOfBirth = pulledData["DateOfBirth"];
                $scope.Level = pulledData["Level"];

            });
        });
    };


}]);
```

Comment: You've built it on Angular, so use Angular. And do you really mean two-way?

Comment: Too generic question. Go to angularjs site and go through some tutorials. Everything will become clear (or your questions will become more specific)

Comment: use angular. Get the response, put it in a scope variable and use it there. By two way if you mean one way front-end and other the database end (direct DML), i don't think two way works that way

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I know I have to use Angular but how to do it is where I'm lost.  

Correct me if I'm wrong, but two-way data binding is when you have a variable in angular but also in the HTML, so when the variable gets assigned it updates in the view automatically.

This is what I'm trying to do! My current goal is to be able to show the backend information in the frontend!

Thanks for your reply pal.

Comment: No. That's simply one-way data-binding: you modify something in the model, and the view is updated. Two-way is when you can also modify something in the vew (typically, the text of an input field), and the model is updated. All you need is `$scope.person = dataFromDatatase.results;` in the controller, and `{{ person.Name }}` in the view. This is basic Angular stuff. The fact that the data comes from a database is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The result of an $http promise is an object, representing an HTTP response, with the following fields:

- status
- data
- headers
- config

There's no reason to use $scope.$apply(), and you shouldn't put individual fields in the scope. Just put the whole person object:

```
    Person.get(searchOption).$promise.then(function (response) {
        $scope.person = response.data.results;
    });
```

Then in your view:

```
{{ person.Name }} {{ person.Email }} (for example)
```

I strongly suggest you take some time learning how to use your browser debugger. You would have found that easily by just inspecting the structure of the response using your debugger (or even just by printing it to the console).

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question, do I need to create a $scope.results.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: When I try to implement your method, I get the error

`angular.min.js:117 TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
    at player.js:37
    at angular.min.js:130
    at n.$eval (angular.min.js:144)
    at n.$digest (angular.min.js:142)
    at n.$apply (angular.min.js:145)
    at l (angular.min.js:97)
    at H (angular.min.js:101)
    at XMLHttpRequest.u.onload (angular.min.js:102)`

Comment: Then it means that what your service returns is not a promise of HTTP response, but a promise of something else. Print what you get, or use your debugger to find out, and change the code accordingly.